Linear approximation problem has me banging my head against the wall
A golfer hits a golf ball at an angle of $\theta=23^{\circ}$ with initial velocity $v=150$ ft/s.
(a) Estimate $\Delta s$ if the ball is hit at the same velocity but the angle is increased by $3^{\circ}$.
(b) Estimate $\Delta s$ if the ball is hit at the same angle but the velocity is increased by $3$.
(Give your answer to four decimal places.)
I assume that $s$ is the distance traveled as a function of $\theta$ and $v_0$ and is defined as
$$s=\frac{v_0^2\sin{2\theta}}{g}$$
where $v_0$ is the initial velocity and $g$ is the gravitational constant on Earth equal to $32.1740$ ft/s$^2$.
For (a), since velocity is constant, I differentiate with respect to $\theta$ and get: $$\frac{ds}{d\theta}=\frac{2\cos{2\theta}\cdot150^2}{32.1740}$$
Given that $\Delta v=3$, I can approximate $\Delta s$ with $\frac{ds}{d\theta}\Big|_{x=\frac{23\pi}{180}}\Delta v$ such that
$$\frac{ds}{d\theta}\Big|_{x=\frac{23\pi}{180}}\Delta v=\frac{2\cos{\frac{23\pi}{90}}\cdot150^2}{32.1740}\cdot3$$
which is apparently wrong. At this point my brain is fried and any help is appreciated. I'm probably not using these notations correctly as well. Also, I convert degrees to radians, if it matters.

In calculus we invariably use trig functions whose inputs are in radians. So you'll need to express $\Delta \theta$ in radians.

@JamieRadcliffe ah.. so 3 becomes $\pi/60$?

Right!  (and now some extra characters....)

@JamieRadcliffe extra characters? I figured I’d just add a factor of $\pi$ to the numerator and a factor of $60$ to the denominator

Sorry; it's just that there is a minimum character limit on comments which was not satisfied by me just saying "Right".
